# SQL Server 2012 Script Tasks and exporting Results vis FTp to client server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ftp, job-scheduling

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding how about I do something to this effect:

I need to create a task on sql server that every day at a certain time it will run a script to retrieve data from a table and  export it onto a client machine via FTP .

The results must be transferred in a TSV (tab separated)

So far I have created a Job on Sql that selects all the data from the table and exports it to the C drive from there I am not to sure where to go

Please any advise will be really grateful

Thanks in advance
R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I's start with the **FTP Task** in the Control Flow Items.

Comment: Will I have to create a C# project for this? or is there a application that I can use? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a job step by using OS file level function. copy and paste to FTP server?
After that FTP will pick up the file automatically